# ViewResolver not resolving to view name, but to RequestMapping value

Tags: java, spring-4

My Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/Management/{code}"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index(@PathVariable("code") String code){

    MyDAO dao = new MyDAO();
    List<Entity> list = dao.list(code);
    ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
    view.setViewName("myView");
    view.addObject("list", list);
    return view;
}
```

My dispatcher.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
   </bean>
```

Then when I call

```
/Management/ExampleCode
```

the page say me

```
HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/pages/Management/ExampleCode.jsp
```

The problem is that I want to be returned myView.jsp and not the /Management/ExampleCode.jsp

can anyone help me?